# Why data table return zero value

Tags: c#

The id is working and its record is existed in database. During debugging process I found that `dt.Count`is zero  . why dt return zero value here?

class:

```
 public class UserGroup
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int creator_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? change_date { get; set; }
    public int? changer_id { get; set; }
    public int? deleted { get; set; }

    public UserGroup() { }

    public UserGroup (UserGroupDs.UserGroupRow row)
    {
        UserGroup group = new UserGroup();

        this.id = row.id;
        this.name = row.name;
        this.date = row.created_date;
        this.creator_id = row.creator_user_id;
        this.change_date = row.Ischanged_dateNull() ? null : (DateTime?)row.changed_date;
        this.changer_id = row.Ischanger_user_idNull() ? null : (int?)row.changer_user_id;
        this.deleted = row.IsdeletedNull() ? null : (int?)row.deleted;

    }
}
```

and here is controller:

```
public UserGroup ById(int id)
    {
        UserGroupDs.UserGroupDataTable dt = Dalc.Sel(id, null, 1);
        if (dt.Count < 1) return null; // 
        return new UserGroup(dt[0]);// it suppose to return this
    }
```

and here is Dalc function

```
  public UserGroupDs.UserGroupDataTable Sel(int? id, string name, int mode)
    {
        UserGroupDs ds = new UserGroupDs();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.Config.ConnStr))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spp_adm_userGroup_sel", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id < 1 ? dbNull : id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? dbNull : name.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", Convert.ToInt32(mode));

            FillDataSet(cmd, ds, new string[] { ds.UserGroup.TableName });

        }

        return ds.UserGroup;
    }
```

Comment: can you send dbnull to an `id` field? what is returning from the method `Sel`?

Comment: Because you don't have any data?

Comment: If the count is 0 then clearly there aren't any records in the object.  It seems likely that your data access method is returning an empty table.

Comment: it accessed table successfully but it return 0, why it return 0 where the record is existed

Comment: Easily solved by setting breakpoints in your code and finding out where the values aren't being assigned.

Comment: Check your query on the stored procedure `spp_adm_userGroup_sel`

Comment: because of your useful comment Mr.Pabinator, I managed to solve it. due to name and mode parameters were null, so stored procedure does not return the right record and it was returning null instead. Thanks